# Multiple WHERE conditions in CASE

Tags: php, mysql

Yesterday, a member of stackoverflow helped me change a table in my database with a case from another table. But I need to input one more condition, and don't know where to put it. I have theese two tables:
**liga**

```
uid  |  name  |  games  |  points  |
___________________________________
1    | Daniel |    0    |    0     |
2    | Mikkel |    0    |    0     |
```

and **kamp2**:

```
uid  |  k1    |  k1r    |  k2   |  k2r   |  week  |
__________________________________________________
1    |  1     |  2-1    |  X    |  2-2   |  14    |
2    |  2     |  1-1    |  1    |  2-1   |  14    |
```

To those who haven't got it yet, it's a betting-game, where the user bets on 2 matches (k1 and k2) and a result on both (k1r and k2r).
Let's say the first match is 2-1, i use:

```
UPDATE liga l JOIN
       kamp2 k
       ON l.uid = k.uid
    SET point = (CASE WHEN k.k1 = '1' and k.k1r = '2-1' THEN point + 5
                      WHEN k.k1r = '2-1' AND k.k1 <> '1' THEN point + 3 
                      WHEN k.k1 = '1' AND k.k1r <> '2-1' THEN point + 1 
                      ELSE point
                 END)
    WHERE l.uid = k.uid ;
```

and it workes perfectly. **Daniel** gets 5 points and **Mikkel** gets 3 points. But now to my problem. Next week they will send in another bet with the week-number **15**. So I actually just want it to

```
UPDATE liga l JOIN
       kamp2 WHERE k.week = 15
       ......
```

but it won't allow that. Where should I put the condition then?

Comment: I don't follow the logic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should add the where clause to the end (where the other `where` clause is located).
In sql you first state which tables you like to update `UPDATE table`, then which fields you want to update with what values `SET field='val'` and lastly on which records this should be done `WHERE field=42`.

```
UPDATE liga l JOIN kamp2 k ON l.uid = k.uid 
  SET point = (CASE WHEN k.k1 = '1' and k.k1r = '2-1' THEN point + 5 WHEN k.k1r = '2-1' 
   AND k.k1 <> '1' THEN point + 3 WHEN k.k1 = '1' 
   AND k.k1r <> '2-1' THEN point + 1 ELSE point END) 
   WHERE l.uid = k.uid AND k.week=15 ;
```

Comment: Wow, I tried that like 5 times, and it wouldn't work, and now I copy your code and it actually worked! Well, thank you very much! :) Must have made a mistake im my code before :)

Answer (score 2):

I don't know whether I understood your question,but you can use

```
l.uid = k.uid and k.week = 15
```

or

```
where(case1,case2)
```

The last method is own mysql.